# Сколько стоит и как использовать MongoDB локально для больших проектов?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongo

Нигде не могу найти ответ на свой вопрос. Хочу использовать MongoDB для своего проекта (в связке с React & NodeJs). Проект будет достаточно обширный. Первоначально сервера будут арендованы онлайн, затем будут именно серверные.

Теперь к вопросу. При создании проекта на MongoDB там есть платные услуги. Использовать MongoDB вообще платно? Какие ограничения? Можно ли хранить данные локально? Если да, то как?

Comment: Локально держать базу бесплатно. Но надо какой-то сервер, не на компуктере же своем держать. Вот вам и деньги.. https://www.mongodb.com/database/free. А вот уже какие-то облачные решения платные.

Comment: А где (в какой папке или файле) файлы можно будет найти из базы данных, локально ?